# JQuery Scroll detection fire once

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have a small piece of JQuery designed to collapse my header, change its dimensions, and then stick it to the side of the screen. It all works apart from one part, the height 'toggle' function fires every time the user scrolls, which gets really irritating.

Is there a way I can detect scroll only once OR toggle only once?

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
var width = $(document).width() - 205;
var height = $(document).height();
  $('#me').animate({
    marginLeft: width,
    width: '22px',
    height: 'toggle',
    borderLeftWidth: "10px",
    borderRightWidth: "10px"    
  }, 1000, function() {
    $("#me:first").css("margin-top","-90px");
    var div = $('#me');
    $('#me h1').css("font-size","30px");
    var start = $(div).offset().top;
    $(div).css("height", height);
    $.event.add(window, "scroll", function() {
        var p = $(window).scrollTop();
        $(div).css('position',((p)>start) ? 'fixed' : 'static');
        $(div).css('top',((p)>start) ? '0px' : '');
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: use a flag and set it true onect it fired

Answer (score 10, accepted):

look at jquery's one() functionality http://api.jquery.com/one/

It will only fire once and then promptly remove itself..

Answer (score 4):

use a flag to check it is first time or not

```
var doHeightToggle=true;


$.event.add(window, "scroll", function() {
   if(doHeightToggle)
   {
        var p = $(window).scrollTop();
        $(div).css('position',((p)>start) ? 'fixed' : 'static');
        $(div).css('top',((p)>start) ? '0px' : '');
        doHeightToggle = false;
   } 
});
```