# jQuery Mousewheel plugin trigger only once

Tags: jquery, mousewheel

I am using jquery-mousewheel to detect scroll events.
The thing is that i want to call a function when there is a scroll event, and not call it at every mousewheel event. ( call it only once, at scroll beginning for example )
Is there a way to do this ?

I'd like something like :  :

```
$('.inner').mousewheel( event ){
    my_function_to_be_called_only_once()
}
```

Comment: I hope [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12731795/jquery-scroll-detection-fire-once) is the answer you are looking for

Comment: No, sorry, but I want to keep the event listener. I just want to call my function when there is one mousewheel event, and ignore the other scroll mousewheel events fired.